# Como obter essas linhas e blocos?

Tags: .net, string, regex, vb.net

Estou criando um parser de uma linguagem que estou desenvolvendo, estou tendo problemas para separar as linhas e os blocos do código, segue o código que uso para retornar as linhas:

```vb
Friend Class Splitter
    Public Itens As New List(Of String)
    Private CurrentIndex As Integer = 0
    Private IsOnBlock As Boolean
    Public Sub New(ByVal code As String)
        Dim Returned As String = ""
        Dim Lines As String() = code.Split(vbNewLine)
        Dim I As Int32 = CurrentIndex
        While (Not I >= Lines.Count - 1)
            Dim Text As String = Lines(I).TrimStart
            I += 1
            CurrentIndex = I

            If Text.StartsWith("if ") Then
                IsOnBlock = True
                Returned &= Text & vbNewLine
            ElseIf Text.StartsWith("end ") Then
                IsOnBlock = False
                Returned &= Text
            Else
                Returned &= Text
            End If

            If IsOnBlock Then
                Continue While
            Else
                Exit While
            End If

        End While
        Itens.Add(Returned)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Preciso retornar em cada item no objeto `Itens()` o código da linha e seu devido bloco, por exemplo:

```null
tudo bem com você? isso aqui deve ser um elemento
if iniciou um bloco, vamos capturar tudo nele
     ainda faço parte do segundo elemento
     eu também faço parte do segundo 
end acabou o elemento
aqui já é outra coisa
```

Seguindo em suas respectivas posições e índices dos elementos:

```
0    tudo bem com você? isso aqui deve ser um elemento
1    if iniciou um bloco, vamos capturar tudo nele
          ainda faço parte do segundo elemento
          eu também faço parte do segundo 
2    end acabou o elemento
3    aqui já é outra coisa
```

Mas não estou entendendo **o fato de retornar apenas o primeiro elemento, convém o problema da pergunta.** Em outras palavras, o membro `Itens()` está apenas com o objeto `tudo bem com você? isso aqui deve ser um elemento`, e sem os outros, isso é o que não entendo.

> **Nota:** Também aceito respostas em expressões regulares, tais para ajudar a obter essas linhas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está passando pelas linhas através do `while`. Quando você não está num bloco, você sai dele... por isso só está pegando a primeira linha.

Faça esse teste:

```vb
Friend Class Splitter
    Public Itens As New List(Of String)
    Private CurrentIndex As Integer = 0
    Private IsOnBlock As Boolean
    Public Sub New(ByVal code As String)
        Dim Returned As String = ""
        Dim Lines As String() = code.Split(vbNewLine)
        Dim I As Int32 = CurrentIndex
        While (Not I >= Lines.Count - 1)
            Dim Text As String = Lines(I).TrimStart
            I += 1
            CurrentIndex = I

            If Text.StartsWith("if ") Then
                IsOnBlock = True
                Returned &= Text & vbNewLine
            ElseIf Text.StartsWith("end ") Then
                IsOnBlock = False
                Returned &= Text
            Else
                Returned &= Text
            End If

            If IsOnBlock Then
                Continue While
            Else
                Itens.Add(Returned)
                Returned = ""
            End If

        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```